# How can change the Bold in the Last Name of Awesome-CV

Tags: fonts, awesome-cv

I am using posquit0/Awesome-CV (which is stellar) and creating a resume, but I am wondering how I can either make the either entire name bold (not just the last name) or unbold the last name? I am not sure where in the .csl I need to edit.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The font size, color and series are controlled in the `awesome-cv` class through the commands `\headerfirstnamestyle` for the first name and `\headerlastnamestyle` for the last name. If you want to change the individual parameters, copy the original definitions of the two commands into the preamble of your document, replace `\newcommand` with `\renewcommand` and adjust the definitions accordingly.

Here are 4 different possible examples:

version 1: [image] with `\headerfont\bfseries` and `\color{text}`

version 2: [image] with `\headerfont` and `\color{text}`

version 3: [image] with `\headerfontlight` and `\color{text}`

version 4: [image] with `\headerfont\bfseries` and original colors

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{awesome-cv}

\name{First}{Last}
\mobile{mobile}


% original definition for comparison
%\newcommand*{\headerfirstnamestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{32pt}{1em}\headerfontlight\color{graytext} #1}}
%\newcommand*{\headerlastnamestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{32pt}{1em}\headerfont\bfseries\color{text} #1}}

% uncomment for version 1
%\renewcommand*{\headerfirstnamestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{32pt}{1em}\headerfont\bfseries\color{text} #1}}
%\renewcommand*{\headerlastnamestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{32pt}{1em}\headerfont\bfseries\color{text} #1}}


% uncomment for version 2
%\renewcommand*{\headerfirstnamestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{32pt}{1em}\headerfont\color{text} #1}}
%\renewcommand*{\headerlastnamestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{32pt}{1em}\headerfont\color{text} #1}}


% uncomment for version 3
%\renewcommand*{\headerfirstnamestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{32pt}{1em}\headerfontlight\color{text} #1}}
%\renewcommand*{\headerlastnamestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{32pt}{1em}\headerfontlight\color{text} #1}}


% uncomment for version 4
%\renewcommand*{\headerfirstnamestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{32pt}{1em}\headerfont\bfseries\color{graytext} #1}}
%\renewcommand*{\headerlastnamestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{32pt}{1em}\headerfont\bfseries\color{text} #1}}

\begin{document}
\makecvheader
\end{document}
```